# I want to redact a sentence and return # for every third word in the sentence

Tags: python

Write a function that will redact every third word in a sentence. Make use of the hashtag (#) symbol to redact the characters that make up the word, i.e. if the word is five characters long then a string of five hashtags should replace that word. However, this should not redact any of the following punctuation marks:

apostrophes (')
quotations (")
full stops (.)
commas (,)
exclamations (!)
question marks (?)
colons (:)
semicolons (;)
Arguments:

sentence (string)  →  sentence that needs to be redacted.
Return:

redacted sentence (string) →  every third word should be redacted.

This is the function, but i haven't tried anything, i'm just confused

```
def redact_words(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.split()
    for word in sentence[2:3]:
        for i in word:
            word.replace('i', '#')
            redacted_sentence = 
    return redacted_sentence
### END FUNCTION
```

Expected output

```
sentence = "My dear Explorer, do you understand the nature of the given question?"
redact_words(sentence) ==  'My dear ########, do you ########## the nature ## the given ########?'

sentence = "Explorer, this is why you shouldn't come to a test unprepared."
redact_words(sentence)=="Explorer, this ## why you #######'# come to # test unprepared."
```

please help

Comment: You need to iterate by index and not by word that way you can indentify every third place. Once you identify every third place you need to iterate through the word at that indez and replace the appropriate characters(using if statements to verify if they should be replaced) and insert it back into the sentence at that location(using the index).

Answer (score 1):

```
def redact_words(sentence):
    # split the sentence into individual words
    words = sentence.split(" ")
    # initialize a variable to hold the redacted sentence
    redacted_sentence=""
    # Set a counter for iteration
    i=1
    for word in words:
        # This would select every third word in the sentence
        if i%3==0:
            # When the word has been selected, store it in a variable to
            # perform the redaction operation on it.
            redaction=""
            for character in word:
                # At this point, we want to separate the punctuations from
                # the  letters in the selected word
                if character in '\'".,!?;:':
                    redaction = redaction + character
                else:
                    redaction = redaction +'#'
            # Piece back together the redacted word with the sentence
            redacted_sentence = redacted_sentence+" "+redaction
        else:
            # Piece back together the word not redacted
            redacted_sentence = redacted_sentence+" "+word
        i+=1
    # Return the redacted sentence and remove the spaces.
    return redacted_sentence.strip()
```